# I need to find a way for my API's JsonConfiguration to stop returning default data

Tags: c#, json, api, serialization

I'm building an API where if the user does not enter a date, it becomes standard 01.01.1001 or 01.01.0001 and I need it not to be filled, not even null.

I'm thinking about SerializerSettings but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Are you talking about dates? C# dates can be made nullable. Research nullable types in C#

Comment: Yes, i'm... In case, i need this value of date 01.01.1001 dont be returned in my API if the user dont enter a normal date like 16.06.2020. Yeah nullable types looks more apropriate in my situation, do you have any sugestion how i can apply this in my API?

Comment: Presumably you need to change the date properties of your model to be nullable. Hard to be specific without knowing the specifics of your current code.

Comment: Talking with a workmate now we can't use nullable because this probably will make changes in a lots of thing...

Comment: Can you add some of your, or sample code that can show the problem you are seeing?

Comment: Why would it affect a lot of things? really, changing to nullable in your serialisable DTO object should not really change too many things - you should only be using it as a model for input/output ti the API, not for other purposes within the application. So it should be a fairly small change surface to where the DTO interfaces with the rest of the application, assuming you've got a good design of course.

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: Hi guys, me and my team solved this question using nullable types, thnks to all ;p